# Deserialisation using Qurkus.io and rest-client-reactive-json not working

Tags: quarkus, jsonparser, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-reactive

I am using  [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive#path-parameters) given here to connect with another service. So far the connection to another service works fine. When I get the response as a string it also works fine.

But it fails to deserialize when I try to deserialize as an object.

My pom looks like this.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I am using the sample Class provided in the demo

```
public class Extension {

    public String id;
    public List<String> keywords;

}

//expected return type 
public class ExtentsionWrapper{
     
    List<Extention> extentions;

}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What are you seeing?

Comment: no error nothing just the result is not mapping to the object I posted

Comment: Try adding `@RegisterForReflection(registerFullHierarchy=true)` on `ExtentsionWrapper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manged to make it work .

```
public class Extension {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String id;
    @JsonProperty("keywords")
    public List<String> keywords;

}

//expected return type 
public class ExtentsionWrapper{
    @JsonProperty("extentions")
    List<Extention> extentions;

}
```

adding `@JsonProperty` fixed my serialization issue